# Multiple Hosting View Controllers being generated when using Navigation Links Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am using a hidden Navigation Link to respond to variables being changed on the backend of my app. Here is the flow of what should happen

1. The app receives a signal from the backend in the form of a variable changing to true
2. An alert is presented to the user
3. Acknowledgment of the alert sets a Navigation Link as active (isActive:)
4. A new view should be presented to the user

Everything appears to work except if this process happens multiple times over. Every time the above process occurs, a new Hosting View Controller is created, and eventually, the app stops presenting new views.
[As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBYNw.jpg)

Here is some of the code I am using for navigation:

Alert:

```
.alert(isPresented: $presentAlert)) {
    Alert(title: Text("Title"), message: Text("Message"),
              dismissButton: .default (Text("Ok")) {
                shouldReturnHome = true
              }
          )
        }
```

Navigation Link:

```
NavigationLink(destination:
   ContentView(),
   isActive: self.$shouldReturnHome) {
     EmptyView()
}.hidden()
```

Also. The following warnings printed in the console corresponding to the alert:

```
2021-07-23 11:01:10.887724-0500 [23342:4225074]popToViewController:transition: called on <SwiftUI.UIKitNavigationController 0x11184b800> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.
2021-07-23 11:01:11.344040-0500 [23342:4225074] [Presentation] Attempt to present <SwiftUI.PlatformAlertController: 0x10e0ca600> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x10de0a2d0> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_24NavigationColumn odifier__: 0x10f629db0>) which is already presenting <SwiftUI.PlatformAlertController: 0x10e0c5400>.
```

Any advice is great! I have been stuck with these issues for a few days now with no luck. Thank you!

Xcode 13.0 iOS 15 Dev Beta 3

Comment: Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: You haven't provided a minimal reproducible example but is `ContentView()` an example or do you intend to open multiple `ContentView()`.  If you intend to get to the original `ContentView()` that is usually the first `View` your shouldn't re-create it you should `dismiss` your current `View` somehow

Answer (score 0):

I've recently come across a similar situation. The issue for me was that the destination of my `NavigationLink` created a new `NavigationView` each time to show its content.

Once I noticed the mistake and took that out, the view hierarchy got flattened and looked normal in the view debugger.